# How to print long double with all decimals in qt/c?

Tags: c++, qt, number-formatting

I have following line of code in my program:

```
long double endJD = 2456541.41563;
QString tempString = "";
tempString.append(QString::number((double) endJD));

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(tempString);
msgBox.exec();
```

It runs fine but output comes: 2.45654e+06 and so how can I get output number in desired decimal places? I am okay with some decimals are removed but I want minimum two decimal points in output.

Comment: The *"as it is"* part is alarming. You need to learn what floating point numbers are, how they are stored and where they differ from decimal numbers you are used to in every day life.

Comment: @IInspectable: Exactly. You can't print a floating-point number "as it is"; it's represented as a sequence of bits. Both the output you're getting, `"2.45654e+06"`, and the output you probably want, `"2456541.41563"`, are human-readable textual translations of the stored value, and both forms are equally valid (though you might have good reasons to prefer one or the other).

Comment: @Keith I interpreted that to mean that the floating point literal `2456541.41563` would be stored to represent this exact decimal number. This is not the case and I have seen too many developers that have difficulties understanding how floating point numbers and decimals relate to ignore phrases like that.

Comment: You can't get _all_ decimal places, truncating `long double` to `double`, unless they have exactly the same mantissa length.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in a format specifier to QString::number.

```
tempString.append(QString::number((double) endJD, 'f'));
```

The formats available from the the Qt docs,

```
e   format as [-]9.9e[+|-]999
E   format as [-]9.9E[+|-]999
f   format as [-]9.9
g   use e or f format, whichever is the most concise
G   use E or f format, whichever is the most concise
```

It will default to "g" if you don't specify one.

Comment: This is still limited to precision of 6. (qt 5.5.1)